# same line on cuircit braker

Tags: electrical

find this scheme one day. Can anyone explain why does L1 comes to the same curcuit braker again from contact 2 to contact 3? a transformer 380/220 V is connected to contacts No. 4 and No. 6 as a consumer of electrical energy

[image]

Comment: If all the info was there.  probably a first year apprentice problem but with the info provided your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: What else do you need to know?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not Home Improvement related.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a diagram that typically shows the overload protection connections designed for 3-phase when wired for single phase. The operating physics for tripping these overloads depends on heat being produced by the current. If wired with current only present on 2 phases current won't produce enough heat and will fail to trip accurately.

Comment: do you mean that circuit breaker does not react to single phase short circuit? Where can i red any info about it? Why cant we just use circuit breakers  with 2 modules agains 3 modules?

Comment: @gloriouspanda what NSP is referring to is a *motor overload relay* used as part of a *motor starter*, not a circuit breaker

Comment: but on a sheme there is a circuit braker. I need to know why is L1 goes not to transformer, but goes to contact #3 before it. Why we can not took 2-p circuit braker? it was done on purpose.

Comment: That is the typical way 1Ø are fed through a 3Ø motor overload device. If we were to see full wiring diagram, fault current, short circuit protection, and xformer and motor load characteristics we might see if or why engineer might design something that way, but really seems like a bit from some educational text where the writer is trying to justify some specific fake scenario to prove some tangent. But bottom line, this appears to be off topic, not related to **Home Improvement**, voting to close question.